# windows 10 command line 3rd party commands works only after several attempts

Tags: composer-php, command

I have a weird issue in my Win10 Command line (And Powershell).

It seems i have to enter 3rd party commands several times until the command actually works.
As an example:

If i enter > `composer require package/name`

On the first few attempts it will not react and will not print out any response, than at a random attempt it will execute the command successfully without any errors.

Although it is hot a show stopper, it is very annoying and time consuming.
This happens in many (not all) 3rd party tools (All native window commands work on first attempt)
Examples: composer, php, node ETC.

Please find an attached image as an example.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

[Composer command example - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTCXW.png)

Comment: is your connection slow? composer need to fetch information about the package in the online index first before installing your desired package. you can always use [sysinternals' process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to check what the program did in the background while it got stuck. oh right, anti virus might occasionally blocks your application from running.

Comment: No :) Strong connection. 100mb. It is the same when i run local commands like php